# tf.boolean_mask in loss function: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I am trying to use tf.boolean_mask to get a masked mean difference for image segmentation:

```
def custom_loss(image):
    def loss(predicted_y, target_y):
        pred_mask = tf.math.greater(predicted_y,0.5)
        target_mask = tf.math.greater(target_y,0.5)
        mean_diff = (tf.reduce_mean(tf.boolean_mask(image,pred_mask)) - tf.reduce_mean(tf.boolean_mask(image,target_mask))) ** 2
        return mean_diff
return loss
```

Unfortunately, I am getting a ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, which would logically be caused by the tf.boolean_mask. Any way to do this on Tensorflow 2.0?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, it's not possible. Losses need "continuous" and "differentiable" variables.

Comment: Are you sure you won't go well with an `'mse'` or a `'binary_crossentropy'`?

Comment: This will be used for an application that calculates the quantitative mean value within the mask. Crossentropy does okay in terms of area overlap with the target mask. But I need to further improve the accuracy/spread of measuring the mean value within the mask.